What is causing these siding stain patterns?
This is fiber cement / Hardie board, as far as I know.  Other buildings that were built at the same time nearby have the same thing.  Any idea what is causing these shapes of squares and circles?  It seems the centers of circles are nails.  Wondering if the squares are glue lines.
More importantly, is this an indication of a big problem, or just needs cleaned/painted?
I had a siding expert come out who does similar installs in the area. He said it's moisture behind the panels. That if the builder used a different kind of paper, it wouldn't be as big of a problem, but it's very common for them to use a inferior product and many of the buildings have this issue. His ultimate recommendation was to paint it and didn't think it was a major problem--at least nothing abnormal to this design and construction process.


Is this just smooth finish fiber cement? It is possible they glued them on the back side and this is staining from the glue leeching through. Sad that something so new would exhibit such staining. If this was recent I would contact the contractor / installer and ask for some remediation.

It's 8 years old and yes, a smooth painted fiber cement surface.  I talked to some neighbors and they said it washes off.  I just don't know what would cause it, particularly the shapes.  Thanks for your input!

I would guess that that's just how water happens to run down the surface. If so, cleaning it will solve it for now. There is probably no permanent solution, just put it on your house maintenance schedule.
